# python xml xpath query using tag and attribute with ns

Tags: python, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, lxml

I must be doing something inherently wrong here, every example I've seen and search for on SO seems to suggest this would work.

I'm trying to use an XPath search with lxml etree library to parse a garmin tcx file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<TrainingCenterDatabase xmlns="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2 http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabasev2.xsd">

  <Workouts>
    <Workout Sport="Biking">
      <Name>3P2 WK16 - 3</Name>
      <Step xsi:type="Step_t">
        <StepId>1</StepId>
        <Name>[MP19]6:28-6:38</Name>
        <Duration xsi:type="Distance_t">
          <Meters>13000</Meters>
        </Duration>
        <Intensity>Active</Intensity>
        <Target xsi:type="Speed_t">
          <SpeedZone xsi:type="PredefinedSpeedZone_t">
            <Number>2</Number>
          </SpeedZone>
        </Target>
      </Step>
     ......
     </Workout>
</Workouts>
</TrainingCenterDatabase>
```

I'd like to return the SpeedZone Element only where the type is PredefinedSpeedZone_t. I thought I'd be able to do:

```
root = ET.parse(open('file.tcx'))
xsi = {'xsi': 'http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2'}
    for speed_zone in root.xpath(".//xsi:SpeedZone[@xsi:type='PredefinedSpeedZone_t']", namespaces=xsi):
        print speed_zone
```

Though this doesn't seem to be the case. I've tried lots of combinations of removing/adding namespaces and to no avail. If I remove the attribute search and leave it as `".//xsi:SpeedZone"` then this does return:

```
<Element {http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2}SpeedZone at 0x2595188>
```

as I'd expect.

I guess I could do it inside the for loop but it just feels like it should be possible on one line!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a bit late, but the other answers are confusing IMHO.

In the Python code in the question and in the two other answers, the `xsi` prefix is bound to the `http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2` URI. But in the XML document with the Garmin data, `xsi` is bound to `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`.

Since there are two namespaces at play here, I think the following code gives a clearer picture of what's going on. The namespace associated with the `tcd` prefix is the default namespace.

```
from lxml import etree

NSMAP = {"tcd": "http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2",
         "xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"}

root = etree.parse('file.tcx')

for speed_zone in root.xpath(".//tcd:SpeedZone[@xsi:type='PredefinedSpeedZone_t']",
                             namespaces=NSMAP):
    print speed_zone
```

Output:

```
<Element {http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2}SpeedZone at 0x25b7e18>
```

Comment: I still had to re-read your answer 3 or 4 times but once it clicked, it looked so obvious. Not sure why I couldn't spot that sooner. think this deserves the correct answer, so edited it.

Answer (score 1):

One way to workaround this is to avoid specifying the attribute name and use `*`:

```
.//xsi:SpeedZone[@*='PredefinedSpeedZone_t']
```

Another option (not that awesome as previous one) is to actually get all the `SpeedZone` tags and check for the attribute value in the loop:

```
attribute_name = '{%s}type' % root.nsmap['xsi']
for speed_zone in root.xpath(".//xsi:SpeedZone", namespaces=xsi):
    if speed_zone.attrib.get(attribute_name) == 'PredefinedSpeedZone_t':
        print speed_zone
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, the wildcard attribute did the job and gives my OCD what it needs for the one liner :) I guess it's something odd between the XPath and etree support then.

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails you can still use

```
".//xsi:SpeedZone[@*[name() = 'xsi:type' and . = 'PredefinedSpeedZone_t']]"
```

Using `name()` is not as nice as directly addressing the namespaced attribute, but at least etree understands it.